# Facebook GraphAPI publish a story with tags and mentiones (ReactNative)

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Our Application uses Facebook GraphAPI to publish content to user's Instagram account.

We faced the issue when we use API to publish a story, the API does not allow to use stickers and effects (like the manual stories publishing via Insta app).

Their documentation says that we can use **user_tags** as the array of users who mentioned. But this is not working.

We pass the array like JSON object in the body - but this does not work, the response to create the media is 200, but users have not been tagged.

Who use GraphAPI to publish stories, how to publish content with hastags and mentions of users?

We tried to use the "ReactNative Share" module, but in this case, we can not handle the "media post ID" after a story published, to be able to get the analytics of this media afterwards.